# VBA Excel 2007: Loops insert on the wrong place rows.

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I wrote two loops to compare 2 lists and to insert missing informations from one list into the other.
Unfortunately, the macro inserts in the middle of the runtime only rows below the 1st row. I tried to avoid this with an If-Statement, but then the mistake will start on the 2nd row.

Here is the code:

```
Sub CopyData()

Dim dl_length As Integer
Dim oa_length As Integer
Dim dl_count As Integer
Dim oa_count As Integer

dl_length = Worksheets("download").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
oa_length = Worksheets("overall").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For dl_count = 1 To dl_length
    For oa_count = 1 To oa_length

If Worksheets("download").Range("F" & dl_count) = Worksheets("overall").Range("C" & oa_count) Then
            Worksheets("overall").Range("C" & oa_count).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
            Worksheets("overall").Range("A" & oa_count + 1) = "Search and replace"
            Worksheets("overall").Range("E" & oa_count + 1) = Worksheets("download").Range("L" & dl_count)
       End If

    oa_length = Worksheets("overall").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Next oa_count
Next dl_count


End Sub
```

When I try to

Can you please help me to improve the code?

Comment: Look at `Offset(1)`, what is it your trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when inserting one row, you don't need `oa_length = Worksheets("overall").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1`

instead, `oa_length = oa_length + 1` would work faster.

Also it should be before the `End if`.

But still updating oa_length won't make the `For` loop go one row more.

You must use a `While` or `repeat until` Loop for that purpose.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyData()

Dim dl_length&
Dim oa_length&
Dim dl_count&
Dim oa_count&
Dim Sh_oa As Worksheet
Dim Sh_dl As Worksheet

With ThisWorkbook
    Set Sh_oa = .Sheets("overall")
    Set Sh_dl = .Sheets("download")
End With

With Sh_oa
    oa_length = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'i removed the +1, wich is a blank cell
End With

With Sh_dl
    dl_length = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

With Application 'this part is to make things faster...
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

For dl_count = 1 To dl_length

    While oa_count <= oa_length

        oa_count = oa_count + 1

        If Sh_dl.Range("F" & dl_count).Value2 = Sh_oa.Range("C" & oa_count).Value2 Then

            oa_count = oa_count + 1 'if you insert a line, you'll need to read a line after that later

            With Sh_oa
                .Rows(oa_count).Insert
                .Cells(oa_count, 1).Value2 = "Search and replace"
                .Range("E" & oa_count).Value2 = Sh_dl.Range("L" & dl_count).Value2
            End With

            oa_length = oa_length + 1 'wider the scope of checks

       End If

    Wend

Next dl_count

Set Sh_oa = Nothing
Set Sh_dl = Nothing


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code works now at me :), but you forget this little thing: Before `while` and after `for` you need: `oa_count = 1`

Comment: yes, nicely spotted, but in fact `oa_count = 0` , so it starts at 1 on first loop (and not 2).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 Worksheets("overall").Range("C" & oa_count).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

with

```
With Worksheets("overall").Range("C" & oa_count).Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Insert
```

A little about `ActiveCell` from good fella MSDN:

> Returns a Range object that represents the active cell in the active
>   window (the window on top) or in the specified window. If the window
>   isn't displaying a worksheet, this property fails. Read-only.